# How to calculate diametrically opposite in coordinates(lat, lon) where -90<lat<90 and -180<lon<180

Tags: python, math, coordinates

Given a coordinate point X=(lat, lon) and a the centre of a circle C=(lat_center, lon_center) I want to calculate  the diametrically opposite coordinates of the point X(assuming that X is inside the circle whose centre is C).

For example, if C=(45.9, 180), the diametrically opposite of X=(45.9, -179) should be (45.9, 179).

the following function is an approximation but does not solve the issue of the latitude being between (-90, 90) and longitude (-180, 180).

```
def f(lat, lon, center):
  lat_center = center[0]
  lon_center = center[1]
  dist_lon = np.abs(lon - lon_center) if np.abs(lon - lon_center)<180 else 360 - np.abs(lon - lon_center)
  dist_lat = np.abs(lat - lat_center) if np.abs(lat - lat_center)<180 else 360 - np.abs(lat - lat_center)
  lon_op = lon_center + dist_lon if lon_center + dist_lon != lon else lon_center - dist_lon
  lat_op = lat_center + dist_lat if lat_center + dist_lat != lat else lat_center - dist_lat
  return np.round(lat_op, 2), np.round(lon_op, 2)
```

Comment: How precise do you want the results, and how far is C from X? On the best way: look for geodetic libraries: you calculate distance and direction on a geodetic between X and C, and then you apply direction and distance from C, so you get Y. On shorter distance you may use other tricks (just sphere or also just Cartesian coordinates)

Comment: What are `lat` and `lon`, angles or coodinates?

Comment: lat and lon are coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Add the path from the point to the centre of the circle to the circle coordinates?

C=(0, 0)
X=(1, 1)

C - X = (-1, -1) # (final - initial) path from X > C

C + (-1, -1) = (-1,-1)

Comment: This not normalize latitude between (-90, 90) and longitude between (-180, 180)

Comment: Could you explain that please? Or does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53902475/how-to-normalise-latitude-into-the-range-of-90-to-90

Answer (score 0):

Using formulas and scripts from [this page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), we can:

1 )  Calculate bearing from X to C

```
θ = atan2( sin Δλ ⋅ cos φ2 , cos φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 − sin φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ cos Δλ )
where   
φ1,λ1 is the start point, φ2,λ2 the end point (Δλ is the difference in longitude)
```

2 ) Calculate distance from X to C

```
a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin²(Δλ/2)
c = 2 ⋅ atan2( √a, √(1−a) )
d = R ⋅ c
where   φ is latitude, λ is longitude, R is earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km);
note that angles need to be in radians to pass to trig functions!
```

3 ) Find `Destination point given distance and bearing from start point` using the same bearing and doubled distance

```
φ2 = asin( sin φ1 ⋅ cos δ + cos φ1 ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos θ )
λ2 = λ1 + atan2( sin θ ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos φ1, cos δ − sin φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 )
where   φ is latitude, λ is longitude, θ is the bearing (clockwise from north),
δ is the angular distance d/R; d being the distance travelled, R the earth’s radius
```

(as variant - get distance and bearing from C to X, then use `θ+Pi` to find point in opposite direction with the same distance (not doubled))